# Can Svn 1.8 be used with Emacs 24 vc-svn?

Tags: svn, emacs, tortoisesvn, emacs24

I'm running Emacs 24.3.1 on windows, and using TortoiseSVN 1.8.4 for SVN access.

The problem is that Emacs doesn't recognize my working copies. E.g. `vc-update` returns the message "No fileset is available here", no matter what file I try it on.

`vc-register` on a new file returns "Spawning child process: exec format error"

Is any configuration needed to get the SVN integration to work? Or is SVN 1.8 just not supported?

Comment: One random thing that comes to mind: perhaps setting `vc-svn-program` to the exact path to the executable would improve things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that for some reason Windows group policy was blocking Emacs from running the SVN executable, even though installed in C:\Program Files. Adding an explicit exception solved the problem.

Apparently SVN 1.8 works just as well as SVN 1.7.

Case closed.